# How to open Video playlist/folder in Fullscreen upon startup/login

Tags: windows-10, boot, video, automation

Basically a demo pc playing videos.

There's a folder full of videos I'd like to play, full screen, on repeat and random.

I saw another answer involving vlc and a bat file in the startup folder, but that's for 1 specific video file (i.e. video.avi).

1. I don't see a startup folder in windows 10?
2. Can we do something similar but for a folder of videos without creating a playlist?

Thanks

Comment: Your question would appear to boil down to "where is the startup folder?" As you haven't linked to the question providing the VLC/bat instructions, we don't know whether that would cover your remaining issue. VLC is perfectly capable of being set to fullscreen, random cycle from a list of titles.

Answer (score 1):

Batch script for automatically playing a folder of videos randomly in fullscreen, indefinitely:

```
"PATH_TO_VLC_vlc.exe" "PATH_TO_VIDEOS" --playlist-autostart --fullscreen --loop --random
```

Path to vlc is the explicit path to vlc.exe, and the path to videos is the explicit path to the folder that contains the video files.

Setting to run on startup:

1. Press Windows Key + R and enter `shell:startup`
2. Put the script in the folder that has opened up in explorer

Comment: had to remove repeat, otherwise it would behave like it clicked on repeat, and it would repeat 1 single file eventually. setting repeat random forever in preferences works, so thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I've updated my answer to achieve the desired behaviour without editing settings. Use `--loop` rather than `--repeat`. That's on me for testing with only one file!

Comment: Ah, will take note of that in the future, thanks again @Codesidian!